Do we have a fully precise visualized model of a particular protein undergoing allostery?
Allostery is the process by which a protein's conformation changes as a result of a change in its free energy landscape due to some ligand binding to it. This changes its functional properties, allowing it to influence other processes differently depending on whether a ligand is bounded to it.  For example, a membrane channel might conformationally change into an "open" or "closed" state depending on whether a ligand is bounded to it.
I am wondering if there are simple proteins for which we have either a physical simulation or a detailed visual model of exactly how a binding ligand changes its energy landscape and thereby its conformation?
EDIT: If not for real-world proteins, is it possible that there are "toy models" of allostery, pertaining to (non-biologically relevant) molecules which are very simple and which still undergo a similar process to allostery of real-world proteins?
I am asking this because I am reading about this topic but the discussion is fairly abstract and algebraic.

Likely not. The reason is that proteins and their interactions are rather complex, with different forces (hydrogen bonds, electrostatic interaction, elastic forces, etc.) dominating different levels of structure (primary, secondary, tertiary.) Moreover, protein choses only one of many thermodynamically equivalent configurations - guided ("chaperoned") by the conditions in which it is synthesized and folded.
RNA structures are somewhat simpler, as they are primarily determined by the nucleotide sequence. The simplest model underlies the well-known Nussinov algorithm (simple non-crossing bonds counting), although more complex algorithms account for interaction between the adjacent bonds (stacking), loop elastic energy, and some other factors (google up articles by Zucker.) There's also quantum field based approach to classifying RNA structures (not very much used in practice, but enlightening.) However, I am not sure that much is known about switching configurations - although it definitely happens (e.g., in the context of the alternative splicing in HIV replication.)
(Sorry for not providing references - I am traveling and writing this from a smartphone.)

Thank you! :). I cannot look into this right now, but will later.

Though, is it possible that there are "toy models" of allostery, pertaining not to actual biologically relevant proteins, but hypothetical molecules which are very simple and which still undergo a similar process of allostery? (btw I didn't know that RNA structures undergo allostery, and I'm not quite sure what the function of that would be)

@user56834 it is not exactly allostery for RNA - but the same sequence can be folded differently when synthesized, thus controlling its expression.
